# Ruby on Rails finding records without a reservation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I am making a hotel reservation system. I have models for User, Room, and Reservation. I have used associations to link as follows: (note, pseudo code)

```
User has_many Reservations
User has_many Rooms, through Reservations

Room has_many Reservations
Room has_many Users, through Reservations

Reservation belongs_to Users
Reservation belongs_to Reservations
```

All is working fine, for example I can list a user's reservations and rooms. Now I need to list all rooms which aren't currently reserved. I have tried the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
reservations = Reservation.where('start > ? AND end < ?', Time.now, Time.now).select('room_id')

if reservations.empty?
  @rooms = Room.all
else
  @rooms = Room.where('id not in (?)',
            reservations)
end
```

I wondered if there is an ActiveRecord method which would do this for me? I tried forcing a LEFT JOIN on rooms to get all rooms where the end date < now but that didn't work either.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I've got a messy work around: Loop through all of the rooms, if the room has reservations, loop through each of those and check their end date. It works but it's not pretty is it. Sure this is a simple left join SQL query really!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly did not work? I suggest you create an `on` scope to filter all the reservations, which are active on a given Date. Then you can use `pluck` to get an array of room ids to then fetch the Rooms themselves.

The code could look something like (warning, written from the top of my head, not tested):

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :on, lambda {|day = Date.today| where('start > ? AND end < ?', day, day) }
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.free_on(day = Date.today)
    reserved_room_ids = Reservation.on(day).pluck('DISTINCT room_id')
    where('id NOT IN (?)', reserved_room_ids)
  end

  def self.reserved_on(day = Date.today)
    reserved_room_ids = Reservation.on(day).pluck('DISTINCT room_id')
    where(:id => reserved_room_ids)
  end
end
```

Now you can use `Room.free_on` or `Room.free_on(1.day.ago)` to get the free rooms for a given day. I also added the method to get to the reserved rooms.

Comment: This is also a good answer. Named scopes are way under-utilized. Also, kudos for introducing me to the pluck method. Hadn't seen that before. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`exists?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#existence-of-objects) method. It will allow you to see if there are any objects that match the query.